# Looking for most efficient way to calc all distance vectors between set of points in 3D

Tags: python, vector, 3d, distance, processing-efficiency

I want to calculate all distance vectors between a set of points in 3 dimensions. All positions are stored in an array of shape (numberOfPoints, 3). Doing that with two loops takes almost 10 seconds for 1000 points.

The code for that is:

```
    allDistances = np.zeros(numberOfPoints, numberOfPoints, 3)
        for i in range(numberOfPoints):
            for j in range(numberOfPoints):
                if j>i:
                    allDistances[i][j] = allPoints[j] - allPoints[i]
                    allDistances[j][i] = -allDistances[i][j]
```

Now are there any tricks or maybe even a method to use in order to speed up this calculation? Euclidean distances (scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()) unfortunatly are not sufficient in my case, because I have to check every element of a distance vector afterwards for a threshold and possibly manipulate it (minimum image convention). What I have to do there is:

```
    np.where(allDistances > threshold, allDistances%threshold - threshold, allDistances)
    np.where(allDistances < -threshold, allDistances%threshold, allDistances)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not know that numpy subtract is able to elementwise subtract arrays with different length. This gives you the option to easily create an array containing all distance vectors from the ith position out of allPositions to all positions out of allPositions. Note that allPositions has the dimension (numberOfAtoms, 3) and allPositions[i] therefor has the dimensions (1,3). Numpy subtract works like:

```
   allPositions[i] - allPositions = [allPositions[i] - allPositions[0],
                                     allPositions[i] - allPositions[1],
                                     ...,
                                     allPositions[i] - allPositions[numberOfAtoms]]
```

Consequently you can get rid of at least one for loop:

```
    for i in range(numberOfPoints):
        # calculate all distance vectors from the ith atom position in allPositions
        # to every atom position in allPositions
        allDistancs[i] = allPositions[i] - allPositions
```

Comparing speed of the originially posted method and this method I found a factor of 200:

```
import numpy as np

numberOfAtoms = 1000
allPositions = np.random.rand(numberOfAtoms, 3)
allDistances = np.zeros([numberOfAtoms, numberOfAtoms, 3])

def calcAllDis1():
    for i in range(numberOfAtoms):
        for j in range(numberOfAtoms):
            if j>i:
                allDistances[i][j] = allPositions[i] - allPositions[j]
                allDistances[j][i] = -allDistances[i][j]

def calcAllDis2():
    for i in range(numberOfAtoms):
        allDistances[i] = allPositions[i] - allPositions

%timeit calcAllDis1()
3s per loop

%timeit calcAllDis2()
14 ms per loop
```

Is there an even faster way in python to calculate allDistances?